# google analytics api not working with my server

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, server-error

I followed the quickstart to install [google analytics API php](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php) in my server, and it works fine in my first server but did not work in the second, and I don't know what to do?

The error code in seconde server:

```
<strong>
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message:' {
  "error": "invalid_grant"
} '' In C:\Inetpub\vhosts\sourceo.net\dev.sourceo.net\includes\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php:364
Stack trace:
C:\Inetpub\vhosts\sourceo.net\dev.sourceo.net\includes\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php(315): Google_Auth_OAuth2-> refreshTokenRequest (Array)
1 C: \ Inetpub \ vhosts \ sourceo.net \ dev.sourceo.net \ includes \ google-api-php-client \ HelloAnalytics.php (43): Google_Auth_OAuth2-> refreshTokenWithAssertion (Object (Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials))
2 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\sourceo.net\dev.sourceo.net\includes\google-api-php-client\HelloAnalytics.php(118): getService ()
3 {main}
  Thrown in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\sourceo.net\dev.sourceo.net\includes\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php on line 364
</strong>
```

links of phpinfo for both server:

Server 1 (works well): source-code-library.com/phpinfo.php

server 2 (not working): dev.sourceo.net/phpinfo.php

please do not hesitate to ask me if you need further information.

[a demonstration video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8zO0MxX5vwo)

thank you very much

Comment: invalid_grant check the server time.

Comment: And the documentation link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataAuthentication#invalid-grant

Comment: thank you @DaImTo for your reply, i tried to add date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); to the both server to change the time. and the result is the same Server 1 works very  well but server 2 not working

Comment: Your server’s clock is not in sync with NTP. (Solution: check the server time if its incorrect fix it. )

Comment: Yes , Your are right !!! 
Thank you very much for you @DaImTo and Eike_Pierstorff. the solution for me in this link : [Configure Windows Server For The Ntp.Pool.Org External Time Service](https://support.4it.com.au/article/configure-windows-server-for-the-ntp-pool-org-external-time-service/)
i really appreciate your help. best regards